# wkhtmltopdf Knp-snappy custom height/width which unit is expected?

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I´m generating pdf´s from html-pages 
and i want to set a specific width and height to each page of the pdf, i found nothing on the web, but in the bundle theres a pdf.php with

```
protected function configure()
```

where these configurations are :

```
        'page-height'                  => null,
        'page-size'                    => null,
        'page-width'                   => null,
```

so i dont know which unit is expected

so if i set it  to

```
                'page-height' => 600,
                'page-width'  => 1000,
```

where i generate the pdf, it gets much too large, so it cant be pixels 
maybe it has to do with any other option ? heres my call :

```
          $pdfString=$this->knp_snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html, array(
                'orientation' => 'landscape', 
                'enable-javascript' => true, 
                'javascript-delay' => 1000, 
                'no-stop-slow-scripts' => true, 
                'no-background' => false, 
                'lowquality' => false,
                'page-height' => 600,
                'page-width'  => 1000,
                'encoding' => 'utf-8',
                'images' => true,
                'cookie' => array(),
                'dpi' => 300,
                'image-dpi' => 300,
                'enable-external-links' => true,
                'enable-internal-links' => true
            ));
```

I need to have a specific height because now the charts i draw are cut because i dont know the exact height of the generated pdf

for any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`--page-width` and `--page-height` take real world units (as in cm, not pixels)

`--page-size` takes values like "A4", "A5", "Letter", etc.

Although it's probably easier not to touch these values and just play around with the layout you're using, or maybe use `--zoom`, but I'd definitely go for tweaking the layout (maybe have a layout or CSS file specific for generating the PDF)

Comment: thank you very much, now it makes sense, do you have a hint where you have this information from ?

Comment: You can run `wkhtmltopdf -H` from the terminal - there's a dump of the output here though: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to touch the class Pdf inside the bundle 
just in the controller you have to add the options when you call to the methode

```
$response->setContent($this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,array('page-height' =>  200,'page-width' => 50)));
```

and this is the hole controlller acation

```
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Delivery entity.
 *
 * @Route("/generate/pdf/ticket/{id}", name="delivery_show_pdf_ticket")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("ShippiesServiceWebAppBundle:Delivery:ticket.html.twig")
 */
public function generatePDFTicketAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ShippiesCoreBundle:Delivery')->find($id);


    $info = array(
        $entity ->getClient()->getCustomerNumber(),

    );
    $infoText = implode('|', $info);

    $options = array(
        'code'   => $infoText,
        'type'   => 'datamatrix',
        'format' => 'png',
        'width'  => 3,
        'height' => 3,
        'color'  => array(0, 0, 0),
    );

    $barcode =
        $this->get('sgk_barcode.generator')->generate($options);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $html = $this->render('ShippiesServiceWebAppBundle:Delivery:ticket.html.twig', array('entity' =>  $entity,'info'=>$infoText,'barcode'=>$barcode,'base_dir' => $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web' . $request->getBasePath()));
 $response = new Response();



  $response->setContent($this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,array('page-height' =>  200,'page-width' => 50)));
 $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
   $response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename=1.pdf');

    return $response;

}
```